# Actualizar treeview al cerrar una ventana toplevel en tkinter python

Tags: python-3.x, poo, tkinter, class, widget

He terminado de hacer un curso de python y estoy desarrollando una app de control de finanzas personales para ir practicando. He avanzado bastante leyendo stackoverflow y buscando en google pero me he topado con un problema que no he logrado encontrar respuesta. Tengo una ventana con un treeview donde se cargan unos datos desde una base de datos en sqlite3.

Aquí el código:

```
# mod_cards.py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox, Toplevel
import mod_addcard, mod_editcard
import fn as fn



class CreditCards(tk.Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
                super().__init__(parent)
                self.parent = parent
                self.parent.title('Listado de Tarjetas de Credito')
                self.parent.geometry('550x250')
                self.parent.config(bg = '#34378b')

                frame = tk.LabelFrame(self.parent, text = 'Tarjetas de Credito', bg = '#34378b', fg = '#ffffff')
                frame.place(x = 10, y = 10)

                self.tree = ttk.Treeview(frame, height = 5, columns = ('#1','#2','#3','#4'))
                self.tree.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10, columnspan = 2, sticky = 'ew')

                self.tree.column('#0', width = 50)
                self.tree.heading('#0', text = 'ID')
                self.tree.column('#1', width = 150)
                self.tree.heading('#1', text = 'Nombre')
                self.tree.column('#2', width = 100, anchor = 'center')
                self.tree.heading('#2', text = 'Cierre')
                self.tree.column('#3', width = 100, anchor = 'center')
                self.tree.heading('#3', text = 'Vencimiento')
                self.tree.column('#4', width = 100, anchor = 'e')
                self.tree.heading('#4', text = 'Total')

                self.tree.bind('<<TreeviewSelect>>', self.selectedItem)

                frameBtn = tk.LabelFrame(self.parent)
                frameBtn.place(x = 10, y = 200)

                tk.Button(frameBtn, text = 'Agregar', width = 17, command = self.open_addcard, bg = '#359f79', activebackground = '#309070', fg = '#ffffff').grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 5)
                tk.Button(frameBtn, text = 'Editar', width = 17, command = self.open_editcard, bg = '#359f79', activebackground = '#309070', fg = '#ffffff').grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 5)
                tk.Button(frameBtn, text = 'Cerrar', width = 17, command = self.close_cards, bg = '#359f79', activebackground = '#309070', fg = '#ffffff').grid(row = 0, column = 2, padx = 5)

                self.get_cCards()

        def open_addcard(self):
                top_level = tk.Toplevel(self)
                mod_addcard.AddCard(top_level)

        def open_editcard(self):
                top_level = tk.Toplevel(self)
                ecard = mod_editcard.EditCard(top_level)
                iid = self.selectedItem()['text']
                data = self.selectedItem()['values']
                ecard.id = iid
                ecard.editName.insert(0, data[0])
                ecard.editDeadline.insert(0, data[1])
                ecard.editDueDate.insert(0, data[2])
                ecard.editBalance.insert(0, data[3])
        

        def close_cards(self):
                self.parent.destroy()

        
        def selectedItem(self, event = None):
                selItems = self.tree.selection()
                if selItems:
                        selItem = selItems[0]
                lsItem = self.tree.item(selItem)

                return lsItem

        def get_cCards(self):
                records = self.tree.get_children()
                for elements in records:
                        self.tree.delete(elements)
                
                db_rows = fn.run_query(fn.selectDB('creditcards'))

                for row in db_rows:
                        self.tree.insert('', 0, text = row[0], values = row[1:])

        def get_selected_item(self):
                items = self.tree.selection()
                if items:
                        item = items[0]
                selItem = self.tree.item(item)
                return selItem
        


if __name__== '__main__':
        root = tk.Tk()
        app = CreditCards(parent = root)
        app.mainloop()
```

Al presionar el botón editar abre una ventana con los datos de lo que esta seleccionado en el treeview.

Este es el codigo:

```
# mod_editcard.py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import mod_cards as mc
from mod_cards import CreditCards
import fn as fn


class EditCard(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.title('Editar Tarjeta de Credito')
        self.parent.geometry('500x150')
        self.parent.config(bg = '#34378b')

        frame = tk.LabelFrame(self.parent)
        frame.place(x = 10, y = 10)

        tk.Label(frame, text = 'Nombre').grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = 'w')
        self.editName = tk.Entry(frame, width = 20)
        self.editName.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        tk.Label(frame, text = 'Fecha Cierre').grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = 'w')
        self.editDeadline = tk.Entry(frame, width = 10)
        self.editDeadline.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = 'w')
        tk.Label(frame, text = 'Fecha Vencimiento').grid(row = 2, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = 'w')
        self.editDueDate = tk.Entry(frame, width = 10)
        self.editDueDate.grid(row = 2, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = 'w')
        tk.Label(frame, text = 'Total').grid(row = 3, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = 'w')
        self.editBalance = tk.Entry(frame, width = 10)
        self.editBalance.grid(row = 3, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = 'w')

        tk.Button(self.parent, text = 'Actualizar', width = 15, height = 3, command = self.update_cCard).place(x = 340, y = 10)
        tk.Button(self.parent, text = 'Cancelar', width = 15, height = 3, command = self.close_edit_card).place(x = 340, y = 80)

        self.id = 0

    def update_cCard(self):
        iid = self.id
        col = ['name', 'deadline', 'duedate', 'balance']
        query = fn.updateBD('creditcards', iid, col)
        parameters = (self.editName.get(), self.editDeadline.get(), self.editDueDate.get(), self.editBalance.get(), iid)
        if fn.run_query(query, parameters):
            messagebox.showinfo(title = 'Éxito', message = 'El item {} ha sido actualizado con éxito'.format(iid), parent = self.parent)
            self.parent.destroy()
        else:
            messagebox.showwarning(message = 'Se ha presentado un error')


    def close_edit_card(self):
        self.parent.destroy()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = EditCard(parent=root)
    app.mainloop()
```

Lo que quiero lograr es que al cerrar la ventana de edición se actualice el treeview con la modificación realizada.

Desde ya muchas gracias!!!

Comment: No se si aun necesitas ayuda. No puedo probar el código porque no tengo esa base de datos, pero por qué no intentas a eliminar el item del treeview con .delete(iid) e insertar con los datos nuevos .insert(parent,index, iid,**kw). También para no perder el orden, si se va a conservar el id solo modifica los valores: .set(iid, column, value)  Ten en cuenta que a la clase EditCard le pasas el self del treeview, por lo que podrás modificarlo directamente desde un objeto EditCard si lo guardas en el constructor: self.tv = parent

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario. Encontre la opción self.wait_window(top_level) que espera hasta que se cierre la ventana top_level para ejecutar el siguiente codigo, y ahi cargo los datos nuevos en el treeview.